# Partially cancelling a unitary matrix with another raised to a power

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I'm given a unitary matrix $U$ and a unitary matrix $V$. I want to pick a real number $t$ such that $U \cdot V^t$ is "as close as possible" to the identity matrix $I$.

Given this problem, two questions suggest themselves:

1. What's a good measure for "closeness"?
2. How do I compute the best $t$, given this measure?

For example, we could measure closeness using the trace distance, in which case we're trying to minimize $\text{Tr} \left| U \cdot V^t - I \right|$. But this seems to get quite complicated when I try to solve it, even when I use a simple $V$ like $V = \exp\left(i |v\rangle \langle v \right|)$ for some single unit vector $v$.

A simple example of this problem: if you are only allowed to rotate around the X axis, how close can you get to returning an object to its original orientation after it was hit by a general rotation?

How are these kinds of problems normally approached and solved?